# Swift 2 - NSURLConnection call function when finished loading image in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift2, nsurlconnection, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to show a loading image before an image in the `UICollectionViewCell` is loaded.

I can call a function when the image is loaded using `NSURLConnectionDelegate` however, I cannot figure out how to hide the image inside the `UICollectionViewCell` once main image is loaded.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let feedCell = cell as! newsFeedCell

        let pictureURL = NSURL(string: self.newsFeedArray[indexPath.row][1])
                    feedCell.pictureView.hnk_setImageFromURL(pictureURL!)
                    self.requestNSURLconnection(pictureURL!, cellImage: feedCell)
    }


func requestNSURLconnection(url: NSURL, cellImage: newsFeedCell){
    cellImage.loadingImage.hidden = false
    cellImage.pictureView.hidden = true
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
    connection.start()


}


func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!, cellImage: newsFeedCell)
{
    cellImage.loadingImage.hidden = true
    cellImage.pictureView.hidden = false
    print("finisched")
    //loading_view.hidden = true
}
```

If I call the function `connectionDidFinishLoading` without `cellImage the print message shows fine.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The signature for `connectionDidFinishLoading` in `NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate`is

```
connectionDidFinishDownloading(_ connection: NSURLConnection,
                 destinationURL destinationURL: NSURL)
```

which is not what you got. You'll never get the callback you expect.

Comment: thanks. But how can I tell the delegate to check if a cell has finished donwloading?

Comment: The simplest thing is to let the cell download the image it needs.